# Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts

Tags: networking, 18.04, updates, ssh, raspberrypi

I am pretty new to Linux,

When first I SSH into my Pi (through my wireless router), I get the following message.

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
```

`sudo apt-get update` fails to update.

Connecting an HDMI port and using the GUI, I can verify that I am connected to my Wifi, Firefox will not work.

Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS

Here is output of sudo apt-get update

```
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
@RPi:~$ Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic InRelease
Err:1: command not found
@RPi:~$   Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Temporary: command not found
@RPi:~$ Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRele                                     ase
Err:2: command not found
@RPi:~$   Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Temporary: command not found
@RPi:~$ Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates InRelease
Err:3: command not found
@RPi:~$   Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Temporary: command not found
@RPi:~$ Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-security InRelease
Err:4: command not found
@RPi:~$   Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Temporary: command not found
@RPi:~$ Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-backports InRelease
Err:5: command not found
@RPi:~$   Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Temporary: command not found
@RPi:~$ Reading package lists... Done
Reading: command not found
```

This problem randomly occurred today, Please Help!

Comment: Reboot. If the problem persists, then please show us a clear image of the complete `sudo apt-get update` output. The *type* of connection error that you encounter is important: Timeout? Refused?  Reset? Something else?

Comment: A `Failure` means that your Internet connection is not working properly...  Is your Pi showing up on the router's DHCP client list???  If not: have you tried using a cable instead of WiFi?

Comment: Do: `sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`